# Optimizing JS onclick button issue w/o jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, performance

So lately I've been trying to make a "SHOW MORE" and "SHOW LESS" feature with embedded SVG.

The code seems to be working fine, although each time I add another button I have to create completly new function therefore I was wondering if you could help me optimize my code.

Currently it looks like this:

```
<!-- HTML CODE -->
        <button id="hideShow" class="button slide-down">SHOW MORE
          <svg id="showMoreSVG" width="13px" height="10px" viewBox="0 2 13 10">
            <path id="showMorePATH" d="M 1 5 L 1 5 L 5 9 L 9 5 L 5 9"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
```

```
// js code
var button = document.getElementById("hideShow");
var content = document.getElementById("more-text");
let text = button.innerHTML.replace("MORE", "LESS");
let textR = button.innerHTML.replace("LESS", "MORE");

button.onclick = function () {
  if (content.className == "open") {
    content.className = "";
    document.getElementById("hideShow").innerHTML = textR;
    document.getElementById("showMoreSVG").setAttribute("viewBox", "0 2 13 10");
    document
      .getElementById("showMorePATH")
      .setAttribute("d", "M 1 5 L 1 5 L 5 9 L 9 5 L 5 9");
  } else {
    content.className = "open";
    document.getElementById("hideShow").innerHTML = text;
    document
      .getElementById("showMoreSVG")
      .setAttribute("viewBox", "0 -2 13 10");
    document
      .getElementById("showMorePATH")
      .setAttribute("d", "M 1 5 L 1 5 L 5 1 L 9 5 L 5 1");
  }
};
```

Result as img:

[image: show more button]

[image: show less button]

It works based on changing max-height property in css class that is different depending on size of text (some are smaller, some are larger).
For example:

```
#more-text,
#more-text2 {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease;
}
#more-text.open {
  max-height: 1600px;
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease;
}
#more-text2.open {
  max-height: 600px;
}
```

I know that the part of css code can be optimized with jQuery but I don't want to implement it on my website. Rather vanilla javascript or some npm package.

Also I do realize that `content.className = "open";` is invalid way to change class, this is something I have on my todo list so please don't bother with that part.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Curious - are you set on presenting the up/down chevrons as SVG? Do you not utilize any kind of icon library?

Comment: @Kinglish yes I am! It is very useful for me as I can make them in any shape I'd like. I've been checking on some pre-made icons but failed to find a suitable one (for me at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reusable way to do it (though I can't seem to test the SVG - I may have gotted the up/down confused). Basically you initialize all more/less buttons at once (in case there are more than one) and you structure your HTML so each more/less instance is in it's own container. Then you can use [closest(selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [querySelector(selector)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to target the elements you want without using all those ID tags - the ID tags are usefull for somethings but in your case you were reusing them which is strictly forbidden. There's no need for them as you can see.

```js
// js code
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".hideShow");

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      let content = e.target.closest('.hs-container').querySelector('.inner-content');
      let closeme = content.classList.contains('open');
      content.classList.toggle('open')
      e.currentTarget.querySelector('span').innerText = closeme ? "SHOW MORE" : "SHOW LESS";
      let att = closeme ? ["0 -2 13 10", "M 1 5 L 1 5 L 5 1 L 9 5 L 5 1"] : ["0 2 13 10", "M 1 5 L 1 5 L 5 9 L 9 5 L 5 9"];
        e.currentTarget.querySelector('.icon').setAttribute('viewBox', att[0])
        e.currentTarget.querySelector('.icon path').setAttribute('d', att[1])
      }));
```

```css
.inner-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease;
}

.open {
  max-height: 1600px;
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease;
}

svg.icon {
  width: 13px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='hs-container'>
  <div class='inner-content'>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
  <button class="button slide-down hideShow"><span>SHOW MORE</span> 
          <svg class="icon" viewBox="0 2 13 10">
            <path d="M 1 5 L 1 5 L 5 9 L 9 5 L 5 9"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Works lovely, thank you! Although there might be some buttons that I don't want to change it's value between show more and show less (some smaller informations that are quite differ from paragraph above or contain another information) so I came up with solution to pass new attribute from html (data-change) that contains either "false" or "true". And then I put ternary operator that swaps text inside if statement that is not executed unless data-change is true. Is that a correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a class to the buttons and use `.getElementsByClassName` to select them all then attach your event listener while looping/iterating over that collection of buttons. That way you are adding it to all of them at once. Have the listener call a handler function with `this.id` or `this.innerHTML` and use `if then` or a `switch` block to compartmentalize your code.

Note that dynamically created buttons will need to have the event listener attached *after* they're created. You can do that by simply calling the same attach function again. It will not put double events on the prior buttons as only one is allowed.

Use [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)